# SSRS 2016 Mobile report - the bars on the time navigator are sometimes discontiguous

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi

Sometimes there are spaces between the bars in the time navigator.

[image showing the spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Dvz.png)

After expanding the date range in the time navigator, everything displays correctly.

[image after changing date range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czGR7.png)

It doesn't matter if the report is viewed from a browser on a desktop or a mobile device using the Power BI app.

The latest SQL Server Service Pack is installed (SP1 CU5 - 13.0.4451.0).

Is anybody else having this problem or know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi! You should add more tags so you question could reach more people.

Comment: Might be worth reporting: http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/idb-p/Issues